# How to format the wildfly/Jboss startup time in the log?

Tags: wildfly, jboss7.x

The log of Wildfly shows the startup time in the format like **started in 100000ms**. The format I expected is ‘started in **x** minutes **y** seconds’, because ms unit is too long for a enterprise application. How to configure that?

Comment: It can't be configured.

Comment: Why does it matter?  Why do you expect that format?

Comment: @stdunbar Because the startup time is more than 1 minute when the application is deployed, so the ms unit is too long for that. I expect the format like '1 minute : 23 seconds.555'. Actually it doesn't matter, just want to figure out if I can change format.

Comment: @James R. Perkins   Ok, I see that. Thank you!

Comment: It sounds like valid feature request. @Germinate will you open feature request for same at http://issues.jboss.org/.